# How to create a semi-circle in center of a boostrap navbar for logo?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I stuck on creating a semi circle inside the bootstrap navbar like [this](https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/1008348/screenshots/3148401/er2234r24.gif). I created a normal floated nav in bootstrap

```
<header id="header">
    <nav id="main-menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="scroll active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="scroll"><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
                    <li class="scroll"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                    <li class="scroll"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li class="scroll"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li class="scroll"><a href="#meet-team">Team</a></li>
                    <li class="scroll"><a href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
                    <li class="scroll"><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li> 
                    <li class="scroll"><a href="#get-in-touch">Contact</a></li>                        
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div><!--/.container-->
    </nav><!--/nav-->
</header><!--/header-->
```

Here i am trying to replace `<li class="scroll"><a href="#about" class="nav-semi">About</a></li>` for logo appearance like [this](https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/1008348/screenshots/3148401/attachments/667569/homepageuimockup0.1.2final_2x.png) and i tried to apply this css but its not working properly.

```
//mycss
.nav-semi{ 
  height: 220px;
  width: 350px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 490px 490px;
  -moz-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
  background: #f2f2f2 url("http://semantic-ui.com/images/logo.png") no-repeat center;
}
```

Please Help for this problem!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better you can do this stuff using photoshop or sketch.Create semicircled logo and place on the center of the navbar. 
Use this [code](http://codepen.io/Rajaraman6195/pen/BpwgQy)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Trinity School Vellore</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" media="all">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class=" yui3-skin-sam controls-visible guest-site signed-out public-page site homepage">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="header">
        <!--  Mobile Nav Begins  -->

        <div class="row-fluid" id="header-bottom">
            <div class="span12">
                <ul aria-label="Site Pages" role="menubar">

                    <li class="" id="layout_11" role="presentation">
                        <a aria-labelledby="layout_11" href="#" role="menuitem">
                        <span>Admissions</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="" id="layout_12" role="presentation">
                        <a aria-labelledby="layout_12" href="#" role="menuitem">
                        <span>Academics</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="" id="layout_13" role="presentation">
                        <a aria-labelledby="layout_13" href="#" role="menuitem">
                        <span>News & Events</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li id="logo-nav">
                        <a class="logo" href="#"></a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="" id="layout_145" role="presentation">
                        <a aria-labelledby="layout_145" href="#" role="menuitem">
                        <span>Infrastructure</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="" id="layout_15" role="presentation">
                        <a aria-labelledby="layout_15" href="#" role="menuitem">
                        <span>Activities</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="" id="layout_16" role="presentation">
                        <a aria-labelledby="layout_16" href="#" role="menuitem">
                        <span>Contact us</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <!-- Mobile menu starts -->

        </div>
    </div>

    <!---HOMEPAGE BEGINS---->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="portlet-layout row-fluid portlet-column portlet-column-only" id="featured-homepage">

            <!-- Insert Featured Homepage Structures Here -->
            <div class="portlet-dropzone portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-only" id="layout-column_column-1">

                <div class="portlet-boundary portlet-boundary_56_  portlet-static portlet-static-end portlet-journal-content " id="p_p_id_56_INSTANCE_npwnGKsZFqVt_">
                    <span id="p_56_INSTANCE_npwnGKsZFqVt"></span>

                    <section class="portlet" id="portlet_56_INSTANCE_npwnGKsZFqVt">
                        <header class="portlet-topper">
                            <h1 class="portlet-title">
                        <span class="">
                            <img id="rjus_column1_0" src="spacer.png" alt="" style="background-image: url('_sprite.png'); background-position: 50% -496px; background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 16px; width: 16px;"> <span class="taglib-text hide-accessible">Web Content Display</span> </span> <span class="portlet-title-text">Web Content Display</span> </h1>
                            <menu class="portlet-topper-toolbar" id="portlet-topper-toolbar_56_INSTANCE_npwnGKsZFqVt" type="toolbar"> </menu>
                        </header>
                        <div class="portlet-content">
                            <div class=" portlet-content-container" style="">
                                <div class="portlet-body">
                                    <div class="journal-content-article">
                                        <a href="https://prestonhs.org/welcome">
                                            <div class="span4" id="featured-homepage-left" style="background: transparent url('http://placehold.it/660') no-repeat scroll center center / cover ; height: 660px;">
                                                <div class="box">
                                                    <h2>Welcome to Trinity School!</h2>
                                                    <p> </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="https://prestonhs.org/about-preston">
                                            <div class="span4" id="featured-homepage-middle" style="background: transparent url('http://placehold.it/660') no-repeat scroll center center / cover ; height: 660px;">
                                                <div class="box">
                                                    <h2>About Trinity</h2>
                                                    <p> </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="https://prestonhs.org/why_preston">
                                            <div class="span4" id="featured-homepage-right" style="background: transparent url('http://placehold.it/660') no-repeat scroll center center / cover ; height: 660px;">
                                                <div class="box">
                                                    <h2>Why Choose Trinity School</h2>
                                                    <p> </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="entry-links"> </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Happy Coding!!

Comment: Thank you good idea! Code snippet you provided on codepen exactly matches my requirement...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another `ul` for the logo and then set the `border-radius` accordingly. I guess [this link](http://codepen.io/shalineesingh/pen/PWOQja) would clear how to go about it.